# web.xml is missing and <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to true doesn't work with profiles

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I have a spring boot application with a double build, local (fat jar) and war (war).

I handled it this way:

```
<packaging>${application.packaging}</packaging>
...

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <application.packaging>jar</application.packaging>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>war</id>
        <properties>
            <application.packaging>war</application.packaging>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Strangely enough, even though the default profile is dev so the packaging is jar, the eclipse error still pops up. It doesn't seem to have any effect on my build but I still want to get rid of it.
How can I do that?

Comment: Where is `${application.packaging}` defined?

Comment: Apply `spring-boot-maven-plugin` for all just change the packaging.

Comment: @JFMeier as you can see it's a property defined inside the profiles, it is jar for dev and war for war

Comment: Define the packaging as `war` remove the profiles and the maven-war-plugin ...as already mentioned by several people here.

Comment: @Phate No, I cannot see where you set the value for `${application.packaging}`. Is it on the command line? Or in the `<properties>` section?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the plugins from your profiles. Only change the packaging.

```
<packaging>${application.packaging}</packaging>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>  

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <application.packaging>jar</application.packaging>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>war</id>
        <properties>
            <application.packaging>war</application.packaging>
        </properties>       
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This is all you need. Nothing more and nothing less. The war plugin used by Spring Boot is already a newer one which doesn't require a `web.xml` anymore.

Although I would strongly recommend against it and use `war` as packaging for dev as well. You can perfectly well execute the `war` like you can the `jar`. So just build a `war`.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</provided>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

This will build a war file that is both executable as well as deployable. This is all explained in the [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-traditional-deployment) as well. It has a whole section on how to that.

Comment: It's exactly what I want to avoid and the purpose of this topic...why should I keep a war build plugin for my local env?

Comment: Read... Remove that plugin, and only leave the spring boot plugin.

Comment: But this way it would only beat a far jar...or not?

Comment: No it won't. And as stated, I would strongly suggest against building 2 different artifacts. Just build the war in your regular dev as well. YOu can still execute it `java -jar my.war`. It is both executable as well as deployable.